# Bitnami Application Insert Query From Application Access Deined

Tags: php, mysqli, server, phpmyadmin, bitnami

Good day,

I have this problem which I can't insert record/data thru my web app. I am using bitnami as server, I don't any problem with "SELECT" query thru my app but when I tried "INSERT" using mysqli, it won't execute. I looked into my /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log, it says "Access Denied "@localhost". I am using root as the user to connect within my app, the permissions are already granted to this user. Can someone help me? I will really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Edit: On my mysqld.log, it says "Access denied for user 'stats'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". I even tried following this: https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/mysql/#how-to-create-a-database-for-a-custom-application still, its not executing the script on my app.

Comment: Seems like you don't have all the privileges. Try to run MySQL on CLI, and run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost;`

Comment: @Treast I tried that one, but still the same. I even restarted mysql after I ran that script however no luck.

Comment: @Treast I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have also user-rights but on files ? Are they assigned to the correct user/group ?

Comment: @Treast I don't remember assigning user/group to my files. I don't have any problem on "SELECT" queries, its just that I can't "INSERT" query.

Comment: Probably because your database is set on 644 instead of 755. a `SELECT` will only read the file, but the `INSERT` instruction will write into the files. Read this : https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/how-to/troubleshoot-permission-issues/#are-the-permissions-in-your-stack-set-properly